# Does putting the type in front of an already declared variable re-declare it?

Tags: java

I came across this problem in an assignment I'm busy with. I have fixed the error and my program runs fine now, but I am having trouble understanding why the error occurred.

My original code excerpt causing the problem was this:

```
public class VendingMachine {
   int paid=0;
   int charge=0;
   int stock1=0;
   int stock2=0;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   }
   public void initialise(int pd, int chrg, int stck){
      int paid = pd;
      int charge = chrg;
      int stock1 = stck;
      int stock2 = stck;
   }

}
```

This method initialise() was being accessed by another class, but when the other class accessed it I received an error "variable stock1 may not have been initialized".

I fiddled around a bit and eventually got my code to work as I realized I'd unnecessarily put int in front of the variables again. So the changed method that works now is:

```
public void initialise(int pd, int chrg, int stck){
  paid = pd;
  charge = chrg;
  stock1 = stck;
  stock2 = stck;
}
```

By putting "int" in front of my variables again, was I re-declaring them? Why was the original code a problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a variable with the same name as a class member inside a method, it masks the class member. So when you put int in front of your variable (you are declaring it that way), that variable will be a different variable than the one declared in your class, even though it has the same name. You can distinguish between the member and the local variable using this.

```
public class SomeClass {

    int stock1; // declares the class member that lives inside the class

    public void someMethod() {
        int stock1; // declares a new local variable only living inside the method
        stock1 = 5; // writes to the local variable
        this.stock1 = 6; // writes to the class member of the same name
        this.stock1 = stock1; // stores the value of the local variable in the class member
    }

}
```

**Update**

Regarding the second part of your question, why that error was thrown: Are you sure, the error came up with exactly the code you have posted in your question? As far as i can see that should not happen.

Because you do initialize all class members when you declare them (which is not necessary, as java initializes class members of type *int* to 0 anyway) and also assign values to all local variables on declaration in that method (which is necessary, because local variables are not initialized automatically).

The error indicates that you tried to access one of the variables in a situation where it is not guaranteed to have been set. For example something like this:

```
public class VendingMachine {

   // [...]       

   public void initialise(int pd, int chrg, int stck){
      int paid = pd;
      int charge = chrg;
      int stock1; // not initialized
      int stock2 = stck;

      int result = stock1 + stock2; // will give that error

   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will re-declare the variables as local variables. Since local variables take precedence to class members (fields), you will write the parameter values into these local variables, not the fields. What you want is the first approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
int paid = pd;
int charge = chrg;
int stock1 = stck;
int stock2 = stck;
```

The local variables will hide the fields. That's why you need to use `this.` to refer to the class fields

In your

```
public void initialise(int pd, int chrg, int stck){
  int paid = pd;
  int charge = chrg;
  int stock1 = stck;
  int stock2 = stck;
}
```

You assign the values to new local variables created now which will be discarted at the end of the method.